# how to extract data from unstructured text (pdf)

Tags: machine-learning, dataset

i have unstructured data  texte contain information i want to extract for example ihave this text "They have obtained an accuracy of 97 % in detection of DDoS attack which is not high than already existing schemes" and the sort will be like this "accuracy =97% "
i'm all ready doing an preprocessing for my text & i'm trying hard with nltk pipline but no result